# Simple Xpath questions

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this record structure what would be my correct Xpath expression

base is /products/product

1. Select only product records with category = "Wit"
2. Select only product records with non empty brand field

```
    <product>
        <productID>?7804407001751?</productID>
        <name>?Name value?</name>
        <price currency="EUR">?11.?24?</price>
        -<productURL>
            product url value
        </productURL>
        -<imageURL>
            product img url value?
        </imageURL>
        -<description>
            description value
        </description>
        -<categories>
            <category path="Wit">?Wit?</category>
        </categories>
        -<additional>
            <field name="delete">?false?</field>
            <field name="brand">?Amaral?</field>
            +<field name="short_description"></field>
            <field name="deliveryTime">?5 werkdagen?</field>
            <field name="deliveryCosts">?5.?95?</field>
            +<field name="imageURL_2"></field>
            +<field name="imageURL_3"></field>
        </additional>
    </product>
```

Comment: for 1)
/products/product[@categories="wit"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> base is /products/product
>
> 1) Select only product records with category = "Wit"

**Use**:

```
../product[categories/category/@path = 'Wit']
```

> 2) Select only product records with non empty brand field

**Use**:

```
../product[additional/field[@name='brand' and normalize-space()]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these...

1) `/products/product[categories/category/@path='Wit']`

2) `/products/product[additional/field[@name='brand'][normalize-space()]]`

if you want both combined:

```
/products/product[categories/category/@path='Wit' and additional/field[@name='brand'][normalize-space()]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="product">
With 'Wit':
<xsl:value-of select="../product[categories/category/@path = 'Wit']/name"/>
with brandname:
<xsl:value-of select="../product[additional/field[@name='brand' and normalize-space()]]/name"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I'm returning only the Name of the product. If you want all the product details to be returned just remove the '/name' from the 'value-of select'.